# How to Insert image into Sql Server using React Native?

Tags: reactjs, sql-server, react-native

I'm doing it by storing the base64 encoding of image which is very lengthy and make the App slow.

Comment: You can store the image on the server and save photo url in the databse.

Comment: Can you store the images in a file share instead of the database?  The database is an expensive place to store large binary data.

Comment: @RobertSidzinka how can you share some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User form data:

```
let photo = { uri: source.uri}
let formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append("product[name]", 'image')
formdata.append("product[image]", {uri: photo.uri, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg'})
//Image type can be image/png 

fetch('http://192.168.1.0:3000/image',{
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  body: formdata
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("image uploaded")
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })  
}
```